# Executing SHACL JavaScript Extension via org/topbraid/shacl/1.3.2

Tags: javascript, java, shacl

I am trying to learn how to validate RDF graphs by using the SHACL JavaScript Extensions:

https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl-js/

I am trying to execute the ex:germanLabel example here: https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl-js/#js-constraints-example

But I don't manage: I get the exception "Exception: Oracle Nashorn not found in the current context"

I am using shacl-1.3.2.jar from: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/topbraid/shacl/1.3.2/

And I have JDK 19.

I read at "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)" that Nashorn has been removed from JDK 15 onwards.

Does that mean that the only way to execute the SHACL JavaScript extension is to use an outdated JDK, e.g., JDK 8?

Or is there any other option? Does any of you know some sample code that I can download and run?

Thanks
Livio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the successor of Nashorn - GraalVM - can help, but I don't know for sure.

I personally wouldn't invest into SHACL-JS further, as I don't think it has been widely used outside of TopBraid tools. And even there we have removed SHACL-JS support recently, in favour of a more comprehensive JavaScript-based technology that we developed for our product, called Active Data Shapes. Not all W3C drafts make it into standards or de-facto standards.